# How to replace a double 2 consecutive quotes by a space in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string which represents  longitude/latitude in the following format:

dd°mm'ss''W (note 2 single quotes after ss).

And I am using the following code to transform the string in its decimal representation:

```
function dmsTodegrees(val) {
    var s = val.replace('°', ' ');
    s = s.replace("'", ' ');
    s = s.replace("''", ' ');
    var tokens = s.split(' ');
    var result = Number.parseFloat(tokens[0]) + Number.parseFloat(tokens[1]) / 60 + Number.parseFloat(tokens[2]) / 3600;
    if (tokens[3] === 'W' || tokens[3] === 'S') result = -result;
    return result;
}
```

However, it seems that `s = s.replace("''", ' ');` is not doing what is intended, and the the 2 single quotes (') are not replaced by a space. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Note that i have omitted all the error handling here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are trying to replace `°`, `'` and `''` with space in order to split the string with space. Instead of replacing them with space and splitting the string with space, why don't you just split directly?

```
...
var tokens = val.split(/°|'{1,2}/);
...
```

It works like this:

```
"12.34°56.78'90.12''W".split(/°|'{1,2}/)
=> (4) ["12.34", "56.78", "90.12", "W"]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Could you quickly explain what the regexp does and I will accept your answer

Comment: I thought that the regexp is simple enough. Anyway, `|` means OR, `'{1,2}` means one or two occurrences of `'`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `/'{1,2}/g` to replace all ' in the string. If you don't care about the number and want to replace all single quotes, you can just use  `/'+/g`

```js
function dmsTodegrees(val) {
   var s = val.replace('°', ' ');
   s = s.replace(/'{1,2}/g, ' ');

   return s;
}

console.log(dmsTodegrees("dd°mm'ss''W"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For these lines:

```
s = s.replace("'", ' ');
s = s.replace("''", ' ');
```

the first takes every "'" and replaces it with a space.  So the second will never find two quotes together.

**EXCEPT**...replace only works on the first thing it finds.

so

```
"1,2,3,'',4,'',5,''".replace("'", " ").replace("''", ' ')
```

gives you

```
"1,2,3, ',4, ,5,''"
```

Check the answer from @Dij for the better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use single quotes (`'`) with escape sequence(`\'`) inside single quotes for replace function

```js
function dmsTodegrees(val) {
    var s = val.replace('°', ' ');
    s = s.replace('\'', ' ');
    s = s.replace('\'\'', ' ');
console.log(s);
    var tokens = s.split(' ');
    var result = Number.parseFloat(tokens[0]) + Number.parseFloat(tokens[1]) / 60 + Number.parseFloat(tokens[2]) / 3600;
    if (tokens[3] === 'W' || tokens[3] === 'S') result = -result;
    return result;
}
console.log(dmsTodegrees("20°10'30''4"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace two single quotes first and then one single quote.
If you you repace the single quotes first, even two single quotes get replaced by two spaces (as is the case with you).

```
s = s.replace("''"," ");
s = s.replace("'"," ");
```